# How can I get a list of the roles in a system, via the REST API?

Tags: 7, users, services

Similar to [How to Retrieve all Forums](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151781/services-3-how-to-retrieve-all-forums), how can I retrieve the list of roles in a system via the Services REST API?

This is Drupal 7, Services 3.x.

Are roles terms in a taxonomy vocabulary ?

Comment: You would probably have to make your own service for this, they are not in taxonomy terms

Answer (score 0):

1. [Create a custom service resource](http://www.drupalgap.org/node/187), (you'll have to create your own `access callback` and `access callback file`, unless you want to use DrupalGap which is tailored to the link mentioned here)
2. Then in your `callback`, try something like this:

   return user_roles();